# Implementing SHA-256 in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio, sha, sha256

I am trying to implement SHA-256 in MSVC++. I am nearly there, except for extending the first 16 words of the message schedule array into the remaining 48. I have identified my problem to be at this point because it exactly matches the [example from nist.gov](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/SHA256.pdf) until round 17 of the compression algorithm. My code for the message schedule is as follows:

```
//Extend first 16 words into the remaining 48 words of the message schedule array:
for (int k = 16; k < 64; k++)
{
    bitset<32> s0 = rotr(W[k - 15], 7) ^= rotr(W[k - 15], 18) ^= (W[k - 15] >> 3);
    bitset<32> s1 = rotr(W[k - 2], 17) ^= rotr(W[k - 2], 19) ^= (W[k - 2] >> 10);
    W[k] = add(add(W[k - 16], s0), add(W[i - 7], s1));
}

bitset<32> add(bitset<32> a, bitset<32> b)
{
    unsigned long c = a.to_ulong();
    unsigned long d = b.to_ulong();
    return bitset<32>((c + d) % 4294967296);
}

bitset<32> rotr(bitset<32> b, int num)
{
    int temp = (int)b.to_ulong();
    temp = _rotr(temp, num);
    return bitset<32> (temp);
}
```

Where W[0..15] is a copy of the padded message (which matches the example).
Does anyone see a problem? The full code is [here.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L4BpzmpmzLQsKx1dGf8DfM3RwFXq5tHqtf4ExADvPGM/pub) It's about 170 lines.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using bitsets rather than `uint32_t`s?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Very few people know what crypto hash functions are, so you should not really expect an answer from StackOverflow. This site is for specific programming problems.

Comment: There is lots of SHA256 code available in C, it can be easily changed to C++, or you can compare it with your code. You don't have to look at Wikipedia pseudocode . I don't understand the sequence of `^=` operators. It's undefined, at least some people would argue. Also they are being assigned to `rotr` function, maybe it's supposed to be `^` not `=^`

Comment: I am using bitsets over unsigned ints solely because they have several methods built in that are useful, like its to_string function which returns a binary string. The first part of the algorithm involves manipulating strings. I will try using uints but in theory they should behave the same. I did not know where else to ask this question. I am going for a more purely object-oriented C++ and less of a combination with C because my coworkers are slow at making heads or tails of C usually. If they wanted to implement another hash they could quickly follow my work.

Comment: In the bitset documentation, `^=` is the operator for XOR. I tried replacing it with `^` and unfortunately got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but it hasn't been answered or closed, so I assume an answer is still welcome

In extending the first 16 words of the message schedule array into the remaining 48, you probably meant for the third call to the `add` function to read `add(W[k-7], s1)` instead of `add(W[i-7], s1)`

Array index `i-7` is less than zero for the first 7 chunks.